# How to display labels on map, instead of in VBox in IpyLeaflet in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

With the example of CountriesGeoJSON.ipynb file from IpyLeaflet project's repo on GitHub, each time, I click a polygon of a country, a label is displayed after the map widget.[image: Map Widget]

Is there any way I can generate a label on the map, or show attribute of a polygon inside that polygon?

Right now I believe the example tries to show the label below the map in a VBox.

ipyw.VBox([map, label])

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found an alternative solution from another example from the project. That is I can add an HTML widget over a corner of the map and display and change the text in that widget while I am hovering over features.